# Next.js App Stops Responding After a While

Tags: node.js, next.js, systemd

I have a Next.js app that is running via systemd and after a while when I go to refresh the page it gives me a 504 until I restart the process. I noticed it only happens after a certain amount of time (not sure the exact amount, maybe around 20 minutes?) so I tried setting `TimeoutSec` to 300 so it would restart every 5 minute but that didn't seem to work.

Here's my service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Run my node js app in background
[Service]
# This is your node js app file saved location. It will be executed in background when system startup.
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/html/hwgaming/guardbans
ExecStart=/usr/bin/yarn start
Restart=always
User=user
TimeoutSec=300
Group=nogroup
Environment=PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```